# A more efficient way to input notes into piano roll without midi controllers. Logic Pro

Tags: logic-pro

Being from an FL Studio background and not one to use midi controllers but rather clock notes in with my mouse as my preferred way of working, Logic Pro does not seem to accommodate this approach as well as FL studio did.

Having to hit T every time to move between tools seems to slow me down and I wanted to know from those who work that way if there's a faster way to put notes in less clumsily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of Logic you are using.  I use Logic 9, so I'm not sure that the specifics of this will translate to 10, if that is what you are using, but I imagine this function exists somewhere within 10.

In the top right corner there are two mouse tool options.  The left is the primary mouse action, while the right is to create an action for a command+mouse click.  If you set the pencil tool to the secondary mouse action, then you should just be able to hold the command key and enter the notes.  This secondary mouse function appears in the arrange window also, so you can create a separate function there.  Sometimes I will use the automation curve tool in the arrange window.

I also like to copy and paste notes within the MIDI piano roll using the alt+drag and drop shortcut.  That allows me to have a few notes and move a whole set of them to edit/change elsewhere in the MIDI field.

There are a lot of tools in the secondary mouse function that I have used.  Specifically the Velocity tool has been helpful in my MIDI manipulation.

I also prefer to work in the popup window for the piano roll instead of the one that is embedded in the arrange window, as it gives me more space to work with.  In Logic 9 you can access this either using the command+6 shortcut or alt+double click on the region you would like to open.  If you select multiple MIDI regions in the arrange window, you can open all of them at once and the notes from the different regions will all appear in the same window.

Hopefully this helps.  There are a whole lot of other tools and shortcuts that can be very useful for MIDI manipulation.  I won't spend the time to write them up, as they don't specifically relate to your question, but I would recommend looking into the Transform functions.